# Android Studio with Project Files on Local Network Share

Tags: android, networking

Here is my setup:

Android Studio project files in a shared folder on an Ubuntu 14.10 box.

Trying to run Android Studio 1.0.2 on a Windows 8 box with the U: drive mapped to the network share on the Ubuntu box containing the project files.

When I try to 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' I get errors like this:

Error:Error: Failed to create directory: U:\BackedUp\Projects\AndroidStudio\ScorecardManager\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14

If I go create the folder it's looking for (in this case values-14) and try again then I get:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> U:\BackedUp\Projects\AndroidStudio\ScorecardManager\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-tl\values.xml: Error: (The system cannot find the path specified)

And this goes on and on.  I'm using the same user name on each computer.  It seems that each time I try to sync, the file permissions on the project files get reset to 755 and that may be the problem but don't know if it is, and if so, how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: Got the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I have Same Problem ...

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar setup (Arch-Linux) and I have the same issue:

- Project is located at a network drive - folder mounted localy
- Android studio located localy
- Gradle build gives me: `Error:Error: Failed to create directory`

It drove me crazy - couldn't find a solution!! Folder/file permissions where fine... Anyway this is what worked for me:

I just **deleted** the `build` folder and run gradle build again (I let gradle create the `build` folder). Voila! It worked! No clue why...

(In your case `U:\BackedUp\Projects\AndroidStudio\ScorecardManager\app\build`)

Comment: this works for one time after deleting the build folder. It does not work a second time. You have to delete the build folder before every build, which takes too much time.
I have the same problem, search the internet for hours, but unfortunately, no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar setup - the project location is on my personal laptop running windows 7, and android studio running on my desktop system powered by windows 10. i setuped a public shared project folder on my laptop, and mounted it has a drive in my desktop system. working fine even though android studio showing a warning about watching of network folder changes.

i think your problem will be with the usage permission of folders, remember the security of linux systems. setup your samba folder share with guest access and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The 755 permissions thing is an artifact of Samba and Linux interacting. There are a pair of parameters in /etc/samba/smb.conf that you can play with to get the permissions you want:

```
create mask
directory mask
```

They apply on a per-share basis.