# AndroidStudio 1.5.1 fails when project on network

Tags: android-studio

We have an AndroidStudio project that builds correctly on a local (Windows) machine. Next, we need to move the project to a network mounted drive. Next, building the project fails with errors like:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
>
> > Unable to delete directory: Z:\xxx\yyy\projectname\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xhdpi

For another project, we get errors like:

> Error:Error: Z:\develop\fastID\fastID
>   sources\projectname\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\xml\usb_device_filter.xml
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)

The last time we worked on AndroidStudio (some six months ago) we had AndroidStudio version 1.2 and we had no problems with opening a project from the network drive.

This is build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jp.sinfot.printer.sft6145printapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/sft6145printer-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/java_websocket.jar')
}
```

Postscript: it looks like @rdfrahm had [the exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197301/android-studio-with-project-files-on-local-network-share). But the poor guy never got any response...

Comment: Maybe some permission error.... I suspect it may be due to weird windows network permission..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change build.gradle file and try...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "jp.sinfot.printer.sft6145printapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

}
```

Rebuild the project once and then run.
one more thing is that we cant delete any file under debug mode..
i hope this helps you.